# Layout Problems in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, tablelayout

I have a simple layout which is given below. I have set the parent (RelativeLayout) background to a picture and the child table layout to color white. For some reason when I set the color of the tablelayout it makes the parent layout to black (or null). I am not sure what the issue is here, the same is the case if I have linear layout instead of table layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mbi33" android:id="@+id/rl" android:clipToPadding="true">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@color/white">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the color in colors.xml file? **android:background="@color/white"** could be specified if you have specified it in the colors.xml file placed in the **values** folder. Make sure that it is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

> android:layout_width = "mach_parent" --- >  android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
>
> android:layout_height = "mach_parent" --- >  android:layout_height = "fill_parent"

it should work...

if not you can try this adding this too...
android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: I changed the relative layout's width and height and it did not make any difference.

Comment: can you comment the line cliptoPadding and see what would it be up to.